# mod function and type classes in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

i have this line of code in haskell, where `level :: Float`, and  `y :: Int`,

```
mod (floor(fromIntegral y + (level/2))) (floor level)
```

and ghci returns me the following:

```
No instance for (Integral Float)
  arising from a use of `mod'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Integral Float)
```

i try several versions using fromIntegral and floor for example

```
mod (( y + (floor $ level/2))) (floor level)
```

where i tryed to convert `level/2` to an integral, but the same answer is allways returned

I know i have to give mod both Integral arguments, so i can't figure out why the code is wrong ...

Comment: `Prelude> let (y,level)=(77::Int,23::Float) in mod (floor(fromIntegral y + (level/2))) (floor level)` prints `19`.

Answer (score 3):

With `level :: Float` and `y :: Int`,

```
mod (floor(fromIntegral y + (level/2))) (floor level)
```

is valid and produces whatever `Integral` type the caller wants.

```
Prelude> let level = pi :: Float
Prelude> let y = length "foobar"
Prelude> mod (floor(fromIntegral y + (level/2))) (floor level) :: Integer
1
```

Thus the error

```
No instance for (Integral Float)
  arising from a use of `mod'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Integral Float)
```

indicates that you're trying to use the result as a `Float`.

Maybe you want

```
fromIntegral $ mod (floor(fromIntegral y + (level/2))) (floor level)
```

or maybe you need to change the calling context to work with an `Integral` type.